# Html elements from a xpath response not splitting when pipelined into postgresql table

Tags: python, html, postgresql, xpath, scrapy

I've written a webscraper using scrapy that parses html concert data about upcoming concerts from a table on vivid seats http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/awolnation-tickets.html
I'm able to successfully scrape the data for only some of the elements (i.e.eventName, eventLocation, eventCity, and eventState) but when I pipeline the item into the database, it enters the full collection of the scraped data into each row instead of separating each new concert ticket its own row. I saw another SO question where someone suggested  apending each item into a items list but I tried that and got an error. If this was the solution, how could I implement this with both the parse method and the pipelines.py file? In addition to this, I am unable to scrape the data for the date/time , the links for the actual tickets, and the price for some reason. I tried making the column for the date/time the date-time type so maybe that caused a problem. I mainly need to do if my parse method is even structured properly as this is my first time using it. The code for the parse method and the pipelines.py is below. Thanks!

```
def parse(self, response):

    tickets = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]')
    for ticket in tickets:

        item = ComparatorItem()
        item['eventName'] =ticket.xpath('//*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()').extract()
        item['eventLocation'] =ticket.xpath('//*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "name"]/text()').extract()
        item['price'] =ticket.xpath('//*[@class="eventTickets lastChild"]/div/div/@data-origin-price').extract()
        yield Request(url, self.parse_articles_follow_next_page)    

        item['ticketsLink'] =ticket.xpath('//*[@class="productionsTicketCol productionsTicketCol"]/a[@class="btn btn-primary"]/@href').extract()
        item['eventDate'] =ticket.xpath('//*[@class = "productionsDateCol productionsDateCol sorting_3"]/meta/@content').extract()
        item['eventCity'] =ticket.xpath('//*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()').extract()
        item['eventState'] =ticket.xpath('//*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()').extract()
        #item['eventTime'] =ticket.xpath('//*[@class = "productionsDateCol productionsDateCol sorting_3"]/div[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

## pipelines.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Deals, db_connect, create_deals_table


class LivingSocialPipeline(object):
    """Livingsocial pipeline for storing scraped items in the database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_deals_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save deals in the database.

        This method is called for every item pipeline component.

        """
        session = self.Session()
        deal = Deals(**item)

        try:
            session.add(deal)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

        return item
```

Comment: One quick suggestion, if you have issues pipelined to postgresql, then you may ask yourself do you really need to pipe the item in postgresql in this manner. You can alternatively just write your item(s) to json/csv/xml, then cleanse and remodel your data probably before importing into postgresql.

Comment: have you checked that your `deal` object is as you want it to be added?

Comment: @eLRuLL the models.py file seems to correctly construct the model for each ticket its just that for some reason, the scraper can't get the date/time , the links for the actual tickets, and the price now.

Comment: @Anzel I could do that but it seems that it might be more straight forward to simply pipeline straight into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is not inserting data to database but the way you're extracting it. I see you are not using relative xpaths when you iterate over ticket selectors.

For example this line:

```
ticket.xpath('//*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()').extract()
```

will get you all elements with 'productionsEvent' class that are found in response and **not** all elements of this class relative to ticket selector. If you want to get children of ticket selector you need to use this xpath with dot at the beginning:

```
'.//*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()'
```

this xpath will only take elements which are children of ticket selector, not all elements on page. Using absolute xpaths instead of relative ones is very common gotcha [described in Scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths).

Comment: In a tutorial, [link](http://newcoder.io/scrape/part-2/)  I saw that item loaders can be used to parse the data and form the object ( the code used in the tutorial is deprecated though...). I looked at the official scrapy documentation but can

Comment: I found a tutorial that used Item Loaders to parse the scraped data an constructed the item : [link](http://newcoder.io/scrape/part-2/) but the code  is deprecated. I looked at the official scrapy documentation but can't find many examples of how the item loaders are actually used. Do you know of any?

Comment: Thanks! I added the period to the front of the path and it now seems to be working. The other problem I was having was that the date/time , the links for the actual tickets, and the price cannot be scraped from the page for some reason. Does the code I have in the parse method look correct?